# Checkbox Checked problems in win32 api c++

Tags: c++, api, winapi, checkbox

I've this code done in c++ and I want to ask why when I press one CheckBox all of them change status.
Example:

CB1 = Checked
CB2 = UnChecked

CB1 = Press

CB1 = UnChecked
CB2 = Checked

I want just to make work one of them, not the two at the same time.

Here you have the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {

        //Load the background image
        HWND hWndBackground;
        HANDLE hBitmap;
        hBitmap = LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("\header.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        if (hBitmap != NULL)
        {
            hWndBackground = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("image box"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP, 
                0, 0, 470, 130, 
                hwnd, (HMENU)2000, NULL, NULL);
            SendMessage(hWndBackground, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, LPARAM(hBitmap));
        }

        //Load CheckBox1
        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Show Title"),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
            25, 220, 114, 45,
            hwnd, (HMENU)1, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
        CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);

        //Load Textbox1
        CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), TEXT("140"),
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 
            115, 230, 50, 25,
            hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        //Load Label1
        CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"0",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 10, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);

        //Load CheckBox2
        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Show Title1"),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
            25, 250, 114, 45,
            hwnd, (HMENU)2, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
        CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 2, BST_UNCHECKED);

        break;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        BOOL checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1);
        if (checked) {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED); //SetWindowText(hwnd, title or TEXT("algo");

        }
        else {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
            //action("chatlim", 150, 0, 0);
        }

        BOOL checked1 = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 2);
        if (checked1) {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 2, BST_UNCHECKED);
        }
        else {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 2, BST_CHECKED);
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: You don't distinguish in the WM_OMMAND which one was clicked so when a WM_COMAND is received you change both hwnds.

Comment: It's because, everytime you toggle both button states. No matter which one you press

Comment: Create your check box with `BS_AUTOCHECKBOX` flag (instead of `BS_CHECKBOX`) to automatically put the check marks.

Comment: Jerry, How can I distinguish them?

Comment: With BS_AUTOCHECKBOX I get Checked all of them except for the one that I want to check, his state never change(until I check another one)

Comment: I thnk that the problem could be in WM_COMMAND. Is there any way to know what changed inside the form or what element activate WM_COMMAND

Comment: @James, `LOWORD(wParam)` inside of **WM_COMMAND** gives you the control ID which was triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, Just need to use switch and case.

Answer (score 1):

I will leave this code here just in case if someone will want to know how the author resolved that.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
        case 1:
        {
            BOOL checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1);
            if (checked) {
                CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
            }
            else {
                CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
            }
            break;
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        {
            BOOL checked1 = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 2);
            if (checked1) {
                CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 2, BST_UNCHECKED);
            }
            else {
                CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 2, BST_CHECKED);
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```